# Java Asyhronously wait for the http redirection

Tags: java, http, asynchronous

Hi every one it's been two days now i'm trying to resolve my issue.
I have url link i'm trying to call with AsyncHttpClient class and I need to wait for the redirection made by the link. The problem is that the http get request comes back with an http response 200 and with the http content without waiting for the redirection. Could you help me please? 
Here is the code:

```
    private static String getAsyncRedirectedUrlFromUrl(String url) {
    AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new DefaultAsyncHttpClient();
    Future<Response> response = asyncHttpClient.prepareGet(url).execute(new AsyncCompletionHandler<Response>() {

        @Override
        public Response onCompleted(Response response) throws Exception {
            // Do something with the Response
            // ...
            response.getLocalAddress();
            response.getStatusCode();
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        public void onThrowable(Throwable t) {
            // Something wrong happened.
        }
    });
    try {
        System.out.println("Redirection:" + response.get().getHeader("location"));
        return response.get().getHeader("location");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
   }
```

Here is the request link: [Request LINK](http://www.apideeplink.com/transport_deeplink/4.0/BE/fr-fr/EUR/pebe/2/10141.10622.2016-09-01,10622.10141.2016-09-25/air/trava/flights?itinerary=flight%7C-31927%7C833%7C10141%7C2016-09-01T17%3A40%7C10622%7C2016-09-01T20%3A05%2Cflight%7C-31781%7C1443%7C10622%7C2016-09-25T18%3A55%7C13577%7C2016-09-25T20%3A55%3Bflight%7C-31781%7C616%7C13577%7C2016-09-26T06%3A55%7C10141%7C2016-09-26T10%3A35&carriers=-31927%2C-31781&passengers=1%2C0%2C0&channel=dataapi&cabin_class=economy&facilitated=false&ticket_price=259.15&is_npt=false&is_multipart=false&client_id=skyscanner_b2b&request_id=dfd08759-2daa-4415-9f93-28843d9804a9&deeplink_ids=eu-central-1.prod_c38781e0708758979bff9ab5f1c31cf7&commercial_filters=false&q_datetime_utc=2016-08-06T09%3A23%3A30&_tck=YD2aLp6%2BbP%2F8zB%2BnxLmJCKfa4MB%2BAWYokIVhWDlIzZJLf73KLJyMA9oZVVjDtHhFiH5r%2Fb6uFt2y3fARB%2F4JUsh3lH9uDA0bb2P%2FuuUlCM93fMUNw5W10RWkx1BdfCeZ8r7wdF18cOe0UKMMjLgyeQ%3D%3D&api_logo=http%3A%2F%2Flogos.skyscnr.com%2Fimages%2Fpartners%2Fdefault.png&api_pbs=true&app_id=IFDXqvuYYF0q3Xh2PAeSEMlxqjlFnRllKi7817u%2FOehFSntaLrJrj8swZliqXbuw&is_external_partner_app=true) 
And here is the expect result redirection link: [Expect LINK](http://www.tripair.be/fr/AirticketsResults.html?arr=CMN&extendedDates=0&passengersAdult=1&filterTimeDep=17:40&class=Y&passengersInfant=0&isRoundtrip=1&filterTimeArr=20:05&passengersChild=0&dep=BRU&filterPrice=259.15&obDate=01/09/2016&mobile=0&filterCurrency=EUR&filterTimeArrRet=10:35&ibDate=25/09/2016&filterTimeDepRet=18:55&skyscanner_redirectid=FTaMHlvBEeanCQ9NF2HQqw&country=BE&searchfrom=skyscanner)

Thank your help it will very helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request link you provided indeed returns a plain 200 OK, not a redirect.
The redirect you experience with your browser is triggered from javascript, it's not an HTTP redirect (301 and such).

AsyncHttpClient is an HTTP client, not a browser, so it won't execute JS.

If you want to follow such redirect, you have to parse the page, grab the target url, and send a second request manually.

Comment: Thank you for your help :-), i have been able to resolve the issue with Selenium.